# How can I make react wait to get data from Fetch?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

First of all, I'm using useReducer to set State.
when component mounted, this useFetch hook will triggered and
the callback which contains action(type and payload) will set this initial data to State(jobInfo).

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useFetch = (callback, url) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchInitialData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const initialData = await response.json();
    callback(initialData);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInitialData();
  }, []);

  return loading;
};

export default useFetch;
```

but the problem is, when I'm trying to use map, I get `not a function` error
because the `jobInfo` data has not been fetched yet!
so I wonder how can I make it to wait until data is arrived?

```js
const JobList = () => {
  const { jobInfo, loading } = useContext(JobInfoContext);

  console.log(jobInfo);
  jobInfo['data'].map((infos) => console.log(infos));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just check if the data is there. The component will rerender once the state is set:

```js
const JobList = () => {
  const { jobInfo, loading } = useContext(JobInfoContext);

  console.log(jobInfo);
  !loading && jobInfo['data'] && jobInfo['data'].map((infos) => console.log(infos));
}
```